# How to see the builds & releases from within the PBI / BUG details page?

Tags: tfs, build, release

Currently the links tab of a PBI (or BUG) shows the commits as well as the pull requests but I would like to see the build in which those commits were included as well as the releases of that build (when it was released and to which Server)

In short, is there any way to configure TFS to see the build and release details from within the PBI/BUG Details page?

Currently our approach to find out whether a specific PBI has already been deployed, is to start from the Build and Release menu and to click through all recent releases and their builds until we find the PBI we are interested in. That is not an efficient Approach.

Comment: Do you just want to get all builds and linked releases of builds for a specific GIT commit? According to`Currently our approach to find out whether a specific PBI has already been deployed`, why not directly use  Integrated in Build field of the **Bug** to track which build fix is resolved in?

Answer (score 0):

I found this and consider it as the answer to my question.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/08/25/automatic-linking-work-items-to-builds/